# Why do we use 'assert not' in this example?

Tags: programming-languages, python, computer-science

My code takes 2 dates and finds the age of those dates in days. In my daysBetweenDates method the instructor uses an assert statement:

```
assert not dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)
```

My question is, why do you have to use 'assert not' in this example and in the signature why is year2, month2, day2 first when in the method dateIsBefore it is year1, month1,day2, year2, month2, day2. Here is the rest of the code.

```
def dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    if year2 > year1:
        return True
    else: #if year1 > year or year1 = year2
        if year2 == year1:
            if month2 > month1:
                return True
            else:
                if month2 == month1:
                    if day2 > day1:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
                return False

        return False


def nextday(year, month, day):
    if day < 30:
        return year, month, day + 1
    else: # if day >= 30
        if month < 12:
            return year, month + 1, 1
        else: # month >= 12
            return year + 1, 1, 1


def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    #assert dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)
    **assert not dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)**
    days = 0
    while dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
        year1, month1, day1 = nextday(year1, month1, day1)
        days += 1
    return days
```

Comment: You should probably [ask your instructor](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/64132)

Comment: It's a self paced class so the instructor is not available.

Comment: if `dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)` returns `true`, then `dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert x < 5
assert not x < 1
```

is a way to say

```
assert (1 <= x and x < 5)
```

but, unlike this, will tell you which condition failed.